# Stop query once SQL finds the first result

Tags: sql, sql-server

the program can accept two inputs to search by, using zip code or account number. Trying to make the SQL work with either one, I am using sql server.

```
select name, city, zip, acc_number
 case when zip then zip ='01111'
 when acc_number then acc_number = '00007'
 else NULL end as nodata
from mytable
```

I am probably misunderstanding the case logic, I am trying to say, if zip has value use zip's value and do the search and ignore acc_number and when zip is not true use the value in acc_number, else return NULL.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags

Comment: Please make the question a little clear.

Comment: Are ZIP code and account number two separate parameters in your SQL? How are they being passed in?

Comment: Please provide sample datqa as it is in the tables and expected results as it is imposible to understnd what results you are trying to get

Comment: The page that submits the query has one entry, it can be either a zip code or a account number.  My goal is to do the query by zip if its true or by acc_number if its true

Comment: How are you passing IsZip or IsAccountNumber? What are the parameters you are passing to SQL?

Comment: Either the zip will be passed or  the acc_number.

Comment: I understand. But how do you know the data passed is either Zip or acc_number?

Comment: I have code in place to determine  that. I can also try to do all in SQL, by accepting a value and looking if it matches any where in the zip or in the acc_number field.

Comment: @Andre Take a look at my answer. See if it helps.

Comment: @Andre your question title and your question details seem to contradict each other. Please clarify if you want to 1. _search_ by zip first and if no match is found then search by _acc_number_ or 2. If zip is provided search by zip, though if it is not provided then search by acc_number only

Comment: You should know that these kind of catch-all queries are generally slow because they cannot leverage indexes.  It is usually faster to write two queries and wrap them in an IF..THEN..ELSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that one? It searches by `zip` first. Then if no records found the second part of `union all` searches by acc_number.

```
;with _raw as (
    select
        name, city, zip, acc_number
    from mytable
    where zip ='01111'

    union all

    select
        name, city, zip, acc_number
    from mytable
    where acc_number = '00007'


)
select top 1
    *
from _raw
```

Comment: This would do exactly what the OP is asking for. To the readers, please note that if the parameter passed for zip or the account is null, that subquery will return 0 rows, all comparisons to NULL are false; making ZIP the priority row to be returned before searchign by acct.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that you are already filtering out the parameter to check if it is `zip` or `acc_number` your query should be

```
declare @Zip int = 07652;
declare @acc_number int;

select top 1
name, city, zip, acc_number from mytable
    where 
        1 = case when isnull(@zip,0)!=0 and zip = @Zip then 1 else 0 end
    or 
        1 = case when isnull(@zip,0)=0 and acc_number = @acc_number then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select name, city, zip, acc_number
from mytable
where zip ='01111'
or acc_number = '00007'
```

I am not sure if I have understood your question correctly, but this will search based on the zip being '01111' (and ignoring the acc_number), or searching based on the acc_number being '00007', and ignoring the zip.

If I have misunderstood then please let me know.

Comment: Since questions asks for first result, maybe add TOP 1 to the query

Comment: Hi, a simple 'OR' would not work because one of them could be empty. And there are several records with empty acc_number

Comment: But never add a top 1 without an order by

Comment: My goal is to do the query by zip if its true or by acc_number if its true.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Your question is not 100% clear

```
select name, city, zip, acc_number
 case when zip ='01111' then 'Match'
else when acc_number acc_number = '00007' then 'Match'
 else 'Not match' end as nodata
from mytable
```

Comment: I rather see the case statement after the "where" clause because I will be getting either a value from the zip or from the acc_number to do the search.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a conditional where clause. What this allows you to do is pass in values for either, both, or neither parameters. If both parameters are passed in the results that are returned are based off both conditions. That is, where the account number is what you passed in **AND** the zip code is passed in. If you only pass in one parameter, only that one is used to limit results. If you leave them both `NULL`, all records are returned.

```
declare @zip varchar(16), @acc_number varchar(16)
set @zip = null
set @acc_number = '00007'
if @zip is not null set @acc_number = null

select 
  name, 
  city, 
  zip, 
  acc_number
from 
  mytable
where  
  (zip = @zip or @zip is null)
  and
  (acc_number = @acc_number or @acc_number is null)
```

Comment: OP wanted to ignore the acc_number if the zip was provided; how does your solution accommodate that?

Comment: Not so sure that would work... You don't want to _search_ by zip only, rather, you want to ignore matches of acc_number if you already found a match on zip. I think that this would require a loop or a CTE - sigh.